# How i can Avoid an excessive DOM size in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed, elementor, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to improve my pagespeed score in wordpress. But currently it seems there are around 3300 dom elements. I have created my site in wordpress and currently using elementor page builder to create various pages. how i can reduce accessive dom elements in my size? I have followed web.dev's pagespeed dom reduce based posts but it was not fruitful at all. So what can i do to reduce accessive dom elements?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have tried to add specific screenshot. But i am unable to add that screenshot as of sufficient reputation. I am new here and trying to know the rulea and regulations. I will again try to add screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about reducing DOM elements, there are some things you can do.

Everytime you add a widget, column, inner section or section, it will add additional DOM elements.

So don't add say a second text widget if you could achieve what you want with a single text widget. Likewise for inner sections and sections.

Out of curiosity I built similar pages with just a few paragraphs four different ways. The number DOM elements varied from 46 to 70 depending on how they were constructed (screenshots attached). If you scale this result up to a real life page, it's not an insignificant difference.

Lightspeed ratings are about a lot more than just DOM elements though.

If you aren't already doing so, you can probably get some easy gains if you lazy load images, and then look at caching and other optimising techniques.

There are heaps of good plugins to choose from. I've had good success with https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-cache/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/fast-velocity-minify/ but experiment and find some that work well for you.

[image: test1]

[image: test2]

[image: test3]

[image: test4]